# location manager getting and comparing locations

Tags: android, google-maps

i want to compare the latitude and longitude of my current location to another latitude and longitude.
my code has no errors but nothing happens when my location passes the given latitude and longitude

here is my code:

```
 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION);
        }

    }

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    //Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    Context context=getApplication();
    String text="WRONG DIRECTION";
    int duration=Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    //String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    Toast toast=Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    double c = location.getLatitude();
    double d = location.getLongitude();

    if(c==31.271397&&d==29.999595){

        toast.show();
    }
    else{
        toast.cancel();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the google api key in your manifest ?

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIxcahyugsiaVSPmAjyBHldZP-rMdIE3BhgB81fE" />
        //Maps anykey
    </application>
```

You can use the distanceto function to compare two locations

```
 distanceto = loc1.distanceTo(loc2);

            distanceto = distanceto / 1000;
```

Comment: yes i added the key, the map is working but when my location passes the given lat and long nothing happens.

Comment: You can check my updated answer. Also you can't check if a location is equal to another location. You can just check the proximity and do your calculations based on that.